# Is `npm init <package-spec>` same as `npx <package-spec>`?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-init

The [npm-init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-init) documentation says `npm init <package-spec>` is the same as `npx <package-spec>`:

```
npm init <package-spec> (same as `npx <package-spec>)
```

**Is that correct?** (Ignore the documentation's missing backtick typo.)

If it is correct, why aren't the following two commands equivalent?

```
npm init docusaurus # works as expected
npx docusaurus      # error: could not determine executable to run
```

Answer (score 0):

The [npm-init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-init) documentation is wrong on this point *(and is also missing a backtick)*.  `npm init <package-spec>` is **NOT** the same as `npx <package-spec>`.

The npm init documentation should be corrected to say:

```
npm init <package-spec> (same as `npx create-<package-spec>`)
```

If this correction is applied to the example, you'll find that the following two commands are indeed equivalent:

```
npm init docusaurus
npx create-docusaurus      # Equivalent
```

I've filed two issues:

1. [[DOCS] Missing backtick in synopsis of npm-init #5837](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5837)
2. [[DOCS] Missing 'create-' in synopsis of npm-init #5838](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5838)